# Salesforce.com Lightning App Builder. Working with Custom Lightning Components

Tags: salesforce1-app

Salesforce.com Trail-Head challenge "Working with Custom Lightning Components" has you install an Unmanaged AppExchange Package with a Custom Component.  The package installs in my Developer Org and contains the component.  But the component cannot be found in the Lightning App Builder under standard or custom components.

How do you add a custom component to the lightning app builder?

Answer (score 1):

> To appear in the Lightning App Builder or a Lightning Page, a component must implement the flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes interface.

Source: [Configure Components for Lightning Pages and the Lightning App Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm)

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to meeting the prerequisites details in [Configure Components for Lightning Pages and the Lightning App Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm) (which the ones in the Trailhead package do), you need to enable Lightning Components in your Org before they will appear in the App Builder.

To do so, go to **Develop** > **Lightning Components**. Then tick "Enable Lightning Components" and finally hit <kbd>Save</kbd>.